# My Next.js application routes perfectly EXCEPT on when the page refreshes. URL stays the same, but it displays the home screen. Any help appreciated

Tags: reactjs, typescript, url, next.js

I've created my website in next, SPA with SSR the normal stuff. The issue I'm having is that when I click through the site, everything works perfectly. But when I refresh the page, the URL is correct but it displays my home screen. For the Life of me I cannot figure out the problem.

It's not a complicated site, nothing huge, I'd even be okay with a hard coded solution. This problem ONLY occurs when I have pushed the code to firebase. Locally the site works completely fine on refresh.

I've searched it up and found a big GIT thread about people having the same problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I checked for any redirects, in next config, on my host, etc
I tried to useEffect check when the page loaded, to router.push the right one, didnt work
I tried adding trailingSlash = true to my next config, didnt work
i tried some weird zombie solution chatgpt gave me with router.aspath if statements didnt work

lost as to what it maybe, and debating leaving it as is on the live site since its not the end of the world for an business info site but id like to fix it if possible for the sake of my brain peace

nas